# How do I set a task per hour?

Tags: javascript

I have the following array with all the hours of a working day:

```js
let daySchedule = ["08:00", "09:00", "10:00", ... , "20:00"];

let task = 2; // the number of times a task should be performed during the day
let taskDescription = "Cleaning";
```

The output, in this case, should be:

```
08:00 - Coffee break
**09:00 - Cleaning**
10:00 - Coffee break
**11:00 - Cleaning**
12:00 - Coffee break
**13:00 - Cleaning**]
```

Etc...
I tried to use a For loop and add "Cleaning" to the array, but how do I set it, so that it only displays every 2 rows?

Comment: So to make it clear: do you want that, if task = x, Cleaning is performed every x hours ? One way would be to loop through all the hours and use a modulo function (%) to test whether to perform the task or not. For example if you test hour % 2 === 0 you can only perform the task on even hours.

Comment: another way would to be to have one loop from 1 to 2, (so when === 1 do Coffee Break, and when === 2 do Cleaning) and then repeat that loop until you've reached the end of the day schedule array.

Comment: @Emilien: yes: if task = x, cleaning should be performed every x hours.
I'm not sure how to picture this module function?

Answer (score 0):

So for your question, the code would be:-

```
let daySchedule = ["08:00", "09:00", "10:00", ... , "20:00"];

let task = 2;
let taskDescription = "Cleaning";
let temp= 0;

while(temp!=daySchedule.length){
     temp%task===1 
     ? (console.log(daySchedule[temp] + " " + taskDescription)) 
     : (console.log(daySchedule[temp] + " Coffee Break"))
     temp++;
 
}
```

**Tip :-  Try to use ternary operator instead of if-else for better code quality and understanding**

Comment: can you edit your comment with shift+enter after each line so it will be helpful

Comment: But what if I have 3 tasks that have to be set? 
This is the code so far: 

`
let tasks = [2, 2, 4]; 
let taskDescriptions = [ "Checking vegetables", "Baking bread", "Cleaning", "Free hour" ];
let temp= 0; 

while(temp!=daySchedule.length){ 
    temp%tasks[0]===1 
    ? (console.log(daySchedule[temp] + " " + taskDescriptions[0]))
     : (console.log(daySchedule[temp] + " " + taskDescriptions[3])) 
temp++; } 
`
The outcome should be: 
09:00 - Checking vegetables, Baking bread 
11:00 - Checking vegetables, Baking bread 
12:00 - Cleaning